# OpenLayers change layer on control

Tags: openlayers

I want to change the layer the OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature controls
I've tried removing the controller completely and then adding another based on a new layer.
And I have changed the layer property of the ModifyFeature directly by using a loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if(document.getElementById('verksamhet').selectedIndex === i) {
        controlList.modifyFeature.layer =   window[layerName[i+1]];
    }
}
```

And it almost works; the style gets changed, but the controller only works on the previous layer, like in this picture. (the green is the previous layer, and the only layer the controller responds to, but the style is changed to the correct layer style).

(http://i.imgur.com/w3ZbW.png)

removing the controller and adding a new one is done like this:

```
controlList.modifyFeature.deactivate();
map.removeControl(controlList.modifyFeature);

for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if(document.getElementById('verksamhet').selectedIndex === i) {
        controlList.modifyFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(window[layerName[i+1]], {displayClass: 'modButton', clickout: true, toggle: true, title: 'Modify feature'});
    }
}
map.addControl(controlList.modifyFeature);
controlList.modifyFeature.activate();
```

I think the remove-and-add-a-new-controller-way works, but the problem is that I get duplicates of the controller, i.e. it modifies several layers at once and therefore I believe it doesn't remove the controller in the first place.

Any way to help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also looked at ways to get modifyControl on multiple layers. This is not easy.
On creation of the ModifyControl the layer is set. It also creates a dragControl for that layer. If you use modifyFeature.deactivate() that control is only disabled, not removed. I think that causes the interference you're experiencing.

You should also use modifyFeature.destroy()

```
controlList.modifyFeature.deactivate();
controlList.modifyFeature.destroy();
map.removeControl(controlList.modifyFeature);
```